# Can I move well pipe from under front steps and still satisfy Connecticut code?

Tags: plumbing, code-compliance, pipe, well

I have a problem with my well pipe - it leaks in the spring (when snow melts). As you can see from image below - multiple hack repairs were attempted by previous owners.

[image]

I was going to excavate the outside and redo the pipe. However - it turned out that pipe enters the house under the concrete stairs. Here's a pic we did this summer (had to just backfill it back).

[image]

Here's the problem - If I relocate the pipe so it enters the house in other place bypassing concrete stairs - it would appear that entry point will be only 2.4 ft deep...

So my questions is - if I bust the concrete stairs to fix the pipe - am I then required by code to just leave it under stairs as that would be the only way to satisfy 4 ft requirement?

Comment: Chances are that code allows shallower entry if you insulate properly. How does moving the entry point horizontally resolve the water leak?

Comment: does the pipe enter the house at 4 feet from under the steps?

Comment: @isherwood it doesn't. But if I move it horizontally I won't have to demolish concrete stairs if it leaks again. Then I can easily just dig the hole and fix it.

Comment: @ojait well if you add stairs height to the ground height -> then  yes it makes 4ft+.

Comment: So you're measuring for ground freeze from the top step and not the ground?  What's the measurement from the basement floor to the ground outside?

Comment: @ojait only 2.4 ft

Comment: If you do demo the steps to get to the pipe, install a protective 1 1/2 " ABS sleeve around the pipe.

Comment: @ojait yeah - I think there is already a protective sleeve around it. Some metal like Iron or something similar. But how does that help with building code? Will that make it code-compliant?